# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner tests -- work from ant, not from IDE

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring

I have some tests that load up some Spring context files. When I run the tests from my ant target they work as expected. When I run them from IntelliJ I get a NotWritablePropertyException. I initially figured different classpaths, but the only differences are for IntelliJ's test runner.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionAcknowledgeMode' of bean class [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]: Bean property 'sessionAcknowledgeMode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: The classpaths were not the same, my mistake, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpaths were not the same. Sorry folks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have some classpath issues. Idea may load resource files in a different way from command line ant call.